# Dataflow Spanner API throws IllegalStateException when value of array type column is NULL

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-spanner

I have a dataflow job that writes to Spanner. One of my columns is of type ARRAY which is also nullable. When I try to write a null value for this column from my Dataflow job, I get the following error -

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal call to getter of null value.
at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:501)
at com.google.cloud.spanner.Value$AbstractValue.checkNotNull(Value.java:743)
at com.google.cloud.spanner.Value$PrimitiveArrayImpl.getArray(Value.java:981)
at com.google.cloud.spanner.Value$Int64ArrayImpl.getInt64Array(Value.java:1082)
at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.spanner.MutationSizeEstimator.estimateArrayValue(MutationSizeEstimator.java:79)
at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.spanner.MutationSizeEstimator.sizeOf(MutationSizeEstimator.java:36)
at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.spanner.MutationSizeEstimator.sizeOf(MutationSizeEstimator.java:51)
at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.spanner.SpannerWriteGroupFn.processElement(SpannerWriteGroupFn.java:70)
```

Looks like [this line in MutationSizeEstimator.java](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/io/google-cloud-platform/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/spanner/MutationSizeEstimator.java#L127) which calls [this line in Value.java](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-java/blob/master/google-cloud-spanner/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/spanner/Value.java#L376) is the cause of the error as written in the docs for [Value.java](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-java/blob/master/google-cloud-spanner/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/spanner/Value.java).

> Returns the value of an {@code ARRAY}-typed instance. While the returned list itself
>       will never be {@code null}, elements of that list may be null.
>       @throws IllegalStateException if {@code isNull()} or the value is not of the expected type

Why is this the case? How do I write a null value to a column of type ARRAY then?

Comment: Unfortunately, it is a bug in the Cloud Spanner Dataflow code. I'm going to submit a fix today. As a workaround, if you are inserting a new record you could just skip that field in the mutation builder and it would be set to null. For updates, you could use the `Mutation.newReplaceBuilder` option.

Comment: Please track the progress here https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-3932 and here https://github.com/apache/beam/pull/4951